# Scribe twitter example with callback not working?

Tags: twitter, oauth, scribe

I tried the example, on the scribe page, but with a callback. I always get the error "Could not authenticate with OAuth." the moment i try to use the returned access token.

```
service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(TwitterApi.class)
        .apiKey(config.getTwitterKey())
        .apiSecret(config.getTwitterSecret())
        .callback(config.getServerPath()+"/oauth/twitter")
        .build();

Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken)
```

On the callback then i tried 2 different things, using the request token from the first step or new Token(tokenParam,verifier) but makes no difference, both return a access token that is not working.

```
String tokenParam = request.getParameter(TOKEN);
String verifier = request.getParameter(VERIFIER);
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken,new Verifier(verifier));
```

The response stream with the access token contains user id and display name, so until this step everything seems ok.

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json");
service.signRequest(accessToken, request); // the access token from step 4
request.send().getBody();
```

i tried using the xml url and the json url, but i keep getting the error message in the getBody() method. `{"error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth.","request":"\/1\/account\/verify_credentials.json"}`

EDIT: 
Scribe Debug Output: 
Getting the Access Token

```
15:01:08,136 INFO  [STDOUT] obtaining request token from https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
15:01:08,141 INFO  [STDOUT] setting oauth_callback to http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/oauth/twitter
15:01:08,145 INFO  [STDOUT] generating signature...
15:01:08,380 INFO  [STDOUT] base string is: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F127.0.0.1%253A8080%252Fmyapp%252Foauth%252Ftwitter%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXX%2520%26oauth_nonce%3D583776017%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1346763668%26oauth_version%3D1.0
15:01:08,380 INFO  [STDOUT] signature is: FagkFuKWHMRfoAQFS4tmMMO9FvI=
15:01:08,381 INFO  [STDOUT] appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/oauth/twitter , oauth_signature -> FagkFuKWHMRfoAQFS4tmMMO9FvI= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 583776017 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> XXXXXXXXXX  , oauth_timestamp -> 1346763668 }
15:01:08,382 INFO  [STDOUT] using Http Header signature
15:01:08,383 INFO  [STDOUT] sending request...
15:01:09,564 INFO  [STDOUT] response status code: 200
15:01:09,564 INFO  [STDOUT] response body: oauth_token=dr7cT1xxxxK777Op7fjXeDMCqlY2DdAyyECLnVbhqLI&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxc7qB6pAzjnDrk3fDirakPVKxlS9c&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

Sending the signed request

```
15:01:14,851 INFO  [STDOUT] obtaining access token from https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
15:01:14,852 INFO  [STDOUT] setting token to: Token[dr7cTxxxxxXeDMCqlY2DdAyyECLnVbhqLI , 9ME2xglzfa0xxxxrk3fDirakPVKxlS9c] and verifier to: org.scribe.model.Verifier@96cb5a
15:01:14,852 INFO  [STDOUT] generating signature...
15:01:14,853 INFO  [STDOUT] base string is: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Faccess_token&oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXXXX%2520%26oauth_nonce%3D2130885611%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1346763674%26oauth_token%3Ddr7cTxxxxxXeDMCqlY2DdAyyECLnVbhqLI%26oauth_verifier%3DrbRauznYtglz0eKDtCz7B2yeM%26oauth_version%3D1.0
15:01:14,853 INFO  [STDOUT] signature is: OPJPKxP6veY/U/Fc9ZQU4a7vkaQ=
15:01:14,854 INFO  [STDOUT] appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> OPJPKxP6veY/U/Fc9ZQU4a7vkaQ= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 2130885611 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  , oauth_token -> dr7cT1SLFaK77DdAyyECLnVbhqLI , oauth_verifier -> rbRauznYtgugBLzgQRlz0eKDtCz7B2yeM , oauth_timestamp -> 1346763674 }
15:01:14,854 INFO  [STDOUT] using Http Header signature
15:01:15,792 INFO  [STDOUT] signing request: https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json
15:01:15,792 INFO  [STDOUT] setting token to: Token[15751501-mQZHUAHIzPrYUjwfD4IWvQunC3tTKdUIT4AmdjNvQ , Iw0pNVkhB5Ld4J36sZtiEmawH8XHR9hgvBNgAseTj0]
15:01:15,792 INFO  [STDOUT] generating signature...
15:01:15,796 INFO  [STDOUT] base string is: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Faccount%2Fverify_credentials.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2520%26oauth_nonce%3D139442186%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1346763675%26oauth_token%3D15751501-mQZHUAHIzPrYUjwfD4IWvQunC3tTKdUIT4AmdjNvQ%26oauth_version%3D1.0
15:01:15,796 INFO  [STDOUT] signature is: SziWPSPcEKRq0UE2AvkGvf8rIuo=
15:01:15,797 INFO  [STDOUT] appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_signature -> SziWPSPcEKRq0UE2AvkGvf8rIuo= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 139442186 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  , oauth_token -> 15751501-mQZHUAHIzPrYUjwfD4IWvQunC3tTKdUIT4AmdjNvQ , oauth_timestamp -> 1346763675 }
15:01:15,797 INFO  [STDOUT] using Http Header signature
15:01:17,801 INFO  [STDOUT] {"error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth.","request":"\/1\/account\/verify_credentials.json"}
```

Comment: Can you please turn scribe debug mode on (call `.debug` on the `ServiceBuilder`) and paste the output?

Comment: sorry, took me some time, updated the information in the question.

Comment: Are you using a callback from a WebView?